# UIWebview Deprecated API Usage

Tags: ios, carthage, deprecation-warning

I Integrated few third party framework using Carthage. All libraries are working fine as expected. Apple is going to stop accepting any app that uses UIWebview soon. So I cross checked my project directory by running this command '**grep -r UIWebView .**' , All my framework.dSYM showing matches for UIWebview. Can anybody suggest is this is ok? or do we need to make any changes in project?. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, You need to update your third party framework. Apple stops accepting app which used UIWebView.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this link](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/issues/373) dSYM files do not contain any functional code and depending on the iOS version you are targeting, UIWebView can appear there (as it happens in your case).

In order to check if a framework is using a dependency, you can do the following in a terminal.

```sh
nm FrameworkToBeChecked.framework/FrameworkToBeChecked | grep -i Dependency
```

If no results are shown, the dependency is not contained in the framework. `nm` displays name list (symbol table) of the file.

All credit goes to the author of the comment of the linked page.

Comment: Thanks Miguel lsla for sharing the link. So hoping I don't want to make any changes.