# iOS build not showing activity tab since April 2020

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded to my application build on AppStore. But I have found strange issues I can not showing build on activity tab. This is happen starting from April and I got mail

```
"ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview)."
```

Then I checked my code I have not use `UIWebView` in my whole code. Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: Probably some framework you have included in your code makes reference to UIWebView so your build has been rejected. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60844259/uiwebview-deprecated-api-usage

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked third party library. I used to pod and I updated pod. These are my pods

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~>4.4.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'Alamofire', '~>4.0'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'SKCountryPicker'

Comment: If you are still getting rejected build after the pod update then you can use the nm and grep commands from the answer I linked to to find out which has the reference

Comment: Make sure you are using alamofire 5.0 https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2948

Comment: @Paulw11 I am suing alamofire 4.4.0. So is that issue?

Comment: Actually, re- reading that issue, they state that they don't use UIWebView, so maybe that isn't the problem.  Did you use the commands in the first question I linked to to search for references to UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue before.

I have uploaded my app n got the mail related to UIWebview, so I have coverted the UIWebview to WKWebView and again I uploaded the same. But that time same thing happend again build appear for few minute and just disappears from activity tab. I failed to tackle the problem.

Then I mailed to Apple Developer Support and they replied like Any of the third party library internally using some privacy data you should ask permission for the same.

Then I checked Info.plist, I have given each permission in list still how it comes that we don't understand. Finally then after whole search the one third party library internally using motion related data without permission so this happened. Then I have added that in plist and then again uploaded and its approved.

So please first you check for the webview usage and change it to WKWebView if so and then you can check your info.plist and also check whether your third party library using any privacy sensitive data without permission internally or not. May it help you at some point.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked third party library. I used to pod and I updated pod. These are my pods

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~>4.4.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'Alamofire', '~>4.0'
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'SKCountryPicker'

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I solved my self.
I just write `pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~>4.4.0'` instead of `pod 'GoogleSignIn'` and `pod update` its work. Now I am seen build on Activity tab.